# Moving sprites on a graph in libGDX

Tags: java, movement, libgdx, graph

In my game I'd like to move sprites on a fixed path. Until this point I was trying to stick with the tools already provided by libGDX, like the Tiled map renderer classes so I'm looking for a solution nearly as convenient as that, e.g. I'd like to avoid creating the adjacency matrix by hand. Tiled has the functionality to add objects to the map but I'm not sure if I can use it for this purpose. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the tween engine. [(tweening)](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/Tweening)

It is very powerful and easy to use.
You can create animations for any atribute, timelines with simultaneous and/or sequencial animations, and assign callbacks for starting, ending, looping, etc.